# Even Extension of Heat Equation on Semi-Infinte Domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, even-and-odd-functions

I am working on the heat equation in a semi-inf domain. I am doing an even extension:

$$u(x,t)= \int_{-\infty}^0 G(x-y,t)f(-y)dy + \int_{0}^\infty G(x-y,t)f(y)dy $$
Now in the next step they do:

$$u(x,t)= \int_{0}^\infty G(x+y,t)f(y)dy + \int_{0}^\infty G(x-y,t)f(y)dy $$

How did they do that?
I have tried all of the properties of definite integrals and haven't found anything.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I fixed it! Thanks yall.

Comment: Isn't it just the substitution $y\mapsto -y$?

Comment: @ArcticChar well then wouldn't the dy be affected by such a transformation?

Comment: Yes, but the $-$ coming out is used to switch $\int_\infty^0$ to $\int_0^\infty$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yeah but the negative coming out wouldn't change the sign of the bounds, it would just reverse the order.

Comment: When you do the substitution $y\mapsto -y$, $\int_{-\infty}^0$ becomes $\int_\infty ^0$ right?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, I understand now. Thanks for all of your help (: